# Extrude along normals without intersecting geometry

Tags: normals, extrude

so basically as the title says i am trying to extrude along normals without intersecting geometry but this happen( see images ). Is there a way of doing it on a clean way? Right now the geometry is being messed up all on top of each other. Important: i need to extrude this shape inwards not outward...  When i do it outward geometry does not intersect each other. The problem is going inward. Version of Blender is 2.93.1

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello maybe share your file? I'm not sure you can avoid intersecting geometry actually

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are in a face selection mode.
[image]

Then press `alt+e` or press and hold extrude button.
then a selection box will appear, then select `extrude along normals`

[image]

[image]

hope it'll work.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, maybe i should had say that i need to extrude this shape inwards not outward...  When i do it outward geometry does not intersect each other. The problem is going inward